# Lissajous figure - determine the voltage at channel 2 in canonical form

Tags: voltage, homework, lissajous-figure

I need help with this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot. This is homework, I'm not looking for a ready-made solution, I just need someone to tell me how to start solving this type of task, because I really have no idea.

The task is:

The figure shows Lissajous figure of two simple periodic voltages. If the voltage is on the channel 1 described the expression $$u(t)=3cos(2π100t−π/4)$$ , give the expression for the voltage on channel 2 in the canonical form.

[image: Lissajou figure]

I don't understand why the voltage on the first channel is exactly like this, what exactly should I see from this picture, which I don't notice? I also don't understand what it should mean for the voltage to be represented on the channel in canonical form?

I also found a picture on the internet that gave some of the information on how to look at a figure like this.

[image: Lissajou figure 2]

So, if someone could help me to fix all the problems related to this task that I mentioned, I would be grateful to him. I repeat, I am not looking for a “ready” solution, but just help with the task.
I meet the Lissajous figure for the first time.

Thanks in advance !

Best regards !

Comment: @AJN Yes it is. I didn’t actually mention the real problem with this task, so I made a new post to which I devoted myself.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey sorry about that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 
Corrected.

Comment: Have you seen the page on Wikipedia about the [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_representation). The parametric form of the ellipse is what will be helpful to you. Also since channel one input is `3*cos()`, the maximum value along channel 1 is `3` (represented as `Ax` in the second figure). But the maximum channel 1 value seems to be `4` looking at the figure. Are you sure that the question and the diagram are consistent ?

Comment: @AJN 
The second picture is a picture from the internet, and it does not match the first picture in question, she stated, she gave some information about Lissajous' figures in general.

Comment: @AJN Is it true that the voltage on channel two starts with 3*sin() ?

Comment: Channel 1 is described as \$3\cos(\dots)\$. Maximum value of channel 1 is then `3`; right ? But the maximum value that can be read from the **first picture** is not `3`. It looks like `4` ? So, is the **first picture** consistent with the question ? I'm not sure though.

Comment: @AJN
Yes the first picture refers to the question, ie. image with a black background

Comment: @AJN 
Are you saying that the first picture does not match the voltage given on channel one?

Comment: I am **assuming** that channel-1 moves the trace left/right. in that case what is the maximum left right movement of the trace ? is it 4 or is it 3 ? If the channel-1 is moving the trace up down, then ignore my comment.

Comment: @SrdjanPesevic A systematic approach is to express the waveform of ch. 2 with unknowns, but fixing what you know: you know that the frequency is the same (it's  smooth ellipse), but you don't know the amplitude A and the phase phi (or phase difference with respect to ch. 1). Then you look for  known points such as maxima/minima or zero crossings where you can solve for your 2 unknowns. Note: yes, it looks like ch. 1 is on the y axis (3 divisions of movement, i.e. peak value=3 )

Comment: I come to the solution that: phi=arcsin(B/By); phi=2*pi/9, is that correct ? Finally: 3sin(2pi*100*t - 2pi/9)

Comment: @andrea is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Only guidance is available for homeworks. Do not expect copy and paste ready solutions.

The commentators have already said it: Your x-voltage is sinusoidal. Your xy-plot is an ellipse if the y-voltage also is sinusoidal. Both must have the same frequency, but amplitudes and phase angles can be different. Different x- and y-scales do not affect.

The shown yellow curve looks ellipse, so let's assume it is an ellipse.

So, let your Ux=Acos(Wt+B). Then your Uy=Dcos(Wt+C). As well you can write Uy=Dsin(Wt+E) because sine is phase shifted cosine.

You already know A, W and B. The formula of Uy must fit into the given plot with every t. Choose 2 easy values for t to get equations for D and C (or E).

Check how well you succeeded by remaking the plot or at least few points of it.

Comment: @Srdjan When you have a solution you can plot it "xy", e.g. with Matlab or Excel, and you will see if it resembles the oscilloscope screenshot you have.